# How to add PFS to socket server written in c and openssl

Tags: c, sockets, openssl

I try to add PFS (perfect forward secrecy) to my client-server application.

When I run a server with the following command:

```
openssl s_server -key ./key.pem -cert ./cert.pem -accept 443 -cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA -tls1_2
```

I am able to connect with my client given the following ctx:

```
SSL_CTX* initCTX() {
    SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    SSL_library_init();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    method = TLSv1_2_client_method();
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);

    if(ctx == NULL) {
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            return NULL;
    }

    SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA");

    return ctx;
}
```

When I run my server application with the following ctx:

```
SSL_CTX* init_ssl_ctx() {
    SSL_METHOD const *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    SSL_library_init();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    method = TLSv1_2_server_method();

    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if(ctx == NULL) {
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            abort();
    }
    SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ctx, SSL_SESS_CACHE_OFF);
    SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA");

    // ADDITIONAL CTX MODIFICATIONS TO ENABLE ECDHE

    SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "./cert.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "./key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    return ctx;
}
```

and try to connect with the client, then I get an `no shared cipher` error.
The private key has been created with `openssl genrsa`.

Well my question is: How do I have to modify the ctx to add ECDHE support. I guess that I have to select a curve and I probably need to create and exchange keys for every connection.

Do I still need the private key file? And when yes — what is it used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what I actually missed was the configuration of the Diffie-Hellman parameters and the Elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman. If you do not configure them ...

> the PFS cipher suites will **be silently ignored**.

More information and examples on how to configure and include Diffie-Hellman parameters and Elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman in your C socket server can be found here: http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Diffie-Hellman_parameters

Comment: That statement refers to  or means you must call [`SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh_callback.html). The statement has nothing to do with cipher suites.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ... then I get an no shared cipher error.
>
> How do I have to modify the ctx to add ECDHE support?
> ```

The cipher suite is a product of both client and server capabilities. I find that I need to add 12 to 16 to ensure most clients can be accommodated.

Here's the cipher list I use. It includes the upcoming ChaCha and Poly cipher suites, and include the downlevel client suites. If you *only* want ECDHE, the rdeuce the list even further.

```
// *_CHACHA20_POLY1305 are 3x to 4x faster than existing cipher suites.
//   http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/04/speeding-up-and-strengthening-https.html
// Use them if available. Normative names can be found at (TLS spec depends on IPSec spec):
//   http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-nir-ipsecme-chacha20-poly1305-01
//   http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-mavrogiannopoulos-chacha-tls-02
"TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305:"
"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305:"
"TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_SHA:"
"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_SHA:"

"TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305:"
"TLS_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305:"
"TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_SHA:"
"TLS_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_SHA:"

// Done with bleeding edge, back to TLS v1.2 and below
"TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:"
"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:"
"TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:"
"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:"

"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:"
"TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:"
"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:"
"TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:"

// TLS v1.0 (with some SSLv3 interop)
"TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:"
"TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256:"
"TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:"
"TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:"

"TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:"
"TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:"
"SSL_DH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:"
"SSL_DH_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:"

// RSA key transport sucks, but they are needed as a fallback.
// For example, microsoft.com fails under all versions of TLS
// if they are not included. If only TLS 1.0 is available at
// the client, then google.com will fail too. TLS v1.3 is
// trying to deprecate them, so it will be interesteng to see
// what happens.
"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256:"
"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:"
"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:"
"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:"
```

The ChaCha/Poly cipher suites are available in OpenSSL 1.0.2. So you can test Google's implementation if interested.

---

The RFCs do *not* specify who picks the cipher. By convention, the server usually honors the client's preference. To ensure your server picks the cipher suite, you should add `SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE` to the server's context options. See [`SSL_CTX_set_options(3)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_options.html).

Comment: Well even though I'm using the same version of OpenSSL at the client and the server? I assumed that one cipher that appears in the available ciphers should be enough then?

Comment: @jww - how do you convert the strings in your code sample to a cipher list? I would like to steal it :)

Comment: @Amit - add something like `const char CIPHERS[] = {` as preamble to the list, add `};` as postamble to the list, and then call either [`SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html) or [`SSL_set_cipher_list`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_set_cipher_list.html).

Comment: @jww thanks, that's a good point, but after doing that `SSL_set_ciper_list` fails to select any ciphers now.. my current cipher list is in a different syntax... here it is: `"EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+RC4:EECDH:EDH+aRSA:RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!RC4:!DES"`