# SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list() paradoxically causes "no ciphers available"

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I'm writing a program that communicates over DTLS using OpenSSL with RSA certificates for client and server, signed with `X509_sign(cert, private_key, EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA384"))`.

When I do not restrict OpenSSL in selecting the cipher, it automatically chooses `ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384` to secure the connection (that is what `SSL_get_cipher_list()` returns after the handshake).

And in deed, I think this cipher is a really good option. It uses forward security and up-to-date ciphers.That's why I want to ensure that this cipher is always choosen by calling

```
assert(SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384") == 1);
```

in the beginning.
However, when I do that, the handshake fails with

```
140737353926512:error:140F80B5:SSL routines:DTLS1_CLIENT_HELLO:no ciphers available:d1_clnt.c:851:
```

To me this behaviour is a bit paradox: If I let OpenSSL freely choose the cipher, it selects ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, but it I force it to use it it rejects.
Like a teenager.

Does one of you have a clue what's wrong here?

Comment: Assuming C++ here because of the assert macro.

Comment: Are you sure you're not compiling out SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list() by wrapping it in your assert() macro? To be safe, you should probably be doing something like int ret = SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(...); assert(1==ret);

Comment: @owlstead: I'm using C. C has [assert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h), too

Comment: @NuSkooler: that doesn't work either. And if it *would* be compiled out, I would not expect to get any error and I'd expect to handshake to succeed.

Comment: Are you getting this error on the same server or only on certain servers?

Comment: I'm currently developing this programm and so the client and the server are running on the same machine (my laptop).

Comment: looks like the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765090/how-to-add-pfs-to-socket-server-written-in-c-and-openssl

Answer (score 1):

We need to configure these as well:

After that, we can check the wireshark client.hello and server.hello result

-OpenSSL Preferences:

```
SSL_library_init();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
SSL_load_error_strings();
SSL_CTX *ctx= SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method()); 

// You can use server or client method whether represents your solution, 
but in this solution, client creates the cipher pool and server side selects one of them.

SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);
// you need to use SSL_VERIFY_PEER because you are using a SSL certificate.
// otherwise we can use SSL_VERIFY_NONE

SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, 50); // Passes an int for depth!

SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3); // Use only TLS v1 or later.

SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:@STRENGTH"); // Setting tls1.2 ciphers!

SSL_CTX_set_ciphersuites(ctx, "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"); // Setting tls1.3 ciphers!
```

-Diffie-Hellman groups!

```
int SSL_CTX_set1_groups_list(ctx, "X25519:X448"); // We can add some Diffie-Hellman groups
```

-Signature Algorithms

```
  SSL_CTX_set1_sigalgs_list(ctx, "ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA256"); // We can add some signature algorithms!
```

References:

- -https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set1_sigalgs.html
  -https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html
  -https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Diffie-Hellman_parameters
  -https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_CTX_set1_groups_list.html
  -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765090/how-to-add-pfs-to-socket-server-written-in-c-and-openssl
  -https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_set1_groups.html